# Why Google Search Console coverage reports show excluded pages that don't exist at all

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search

My new website is only about a month old and it has only 27 different web pages. I submitted sitemap.xml to the Google Search Console and it successfully indexed all my pages. However, in the Coverage page apart from my valid urls I can also see 9.000 other **Excluded** urls and 21 **Issues**. When I open the details I see thousands of urls which don't exist on my website at all!
[image]

Here are some example links which don't exist on my website but are reported:
[image]
Now comes the wierdest part, if I search for some of this urls on Google, for example `"/телото-на-ленин-ќе-се-освежи-и-ќе-добие"` I can clearly see that this is a url hosted by another website. While searching for these urls I found that all this urls are actually some older links from other famous Macedonian media websites. And it is not only one website but multiple different existing websites. This is very confusing to me.

**Edit**
Here is a screenshot of the exclusions and the reasons for the exclusions:
[image]

Comment: They are probably pages that existed on the previous version of the website. What is the reason given for their exclusion? I'd suspect it's nothing to worry about as long as they no longer exist. i.e. they are seen as missing pages (404 or 410)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated a screenshot of the reasons. As you can see most of the reasons are  Craw anomaly and Not found (404). But I am suspicious because the examples of invalid urls are actually existing urls on multiple established Macedonian media company websites that I am absolutely sure have never used my domain as they are established brands.

Comment: I checked your site. google recognizes 47 page of your site. maybe google indexed those pages when you was progressing your site and had a mistake in your sites routing system.
I had a problem same as you. google indexed 29k pages of my site Although it had 2k pages because I had a mistake in my websites pagination. after 3 month google recognized my valid pages Although in google webmaster console shows 27k pages that are Excluded.

Comment: I actually managed to find an archive of the domain from 2 years ago and found out that the domain has actually been used for a fake news portal website. Someone created a website and identically copy-pasted news from all the popular news websites in Macedonia. Of course this was short lived while they have gained temporary popularity to make money out of advertisments. But google still remembers the links and now it is slowly excluding them and cleaning up the mess. It is actually a good thing that the links are getting excluded.